# what callback is used for both create and destroy?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I found out from some other posts that cache_counter cant be done on a has_many association, so now I'm trying to do it manually with callbacks. The problem is I heard that after_save doesnt work on delete. i want it to be called after something is created or destroyed. I'm more confused because if resource_tags is modified it wouldnt update the resource properly I dont think :/

In general I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Tags has many resources, and resources has many tags.

I need to ultimately find out how many resources each tag has (i dont care about how many tags each resource has)

tag.rb (not sure about protected here)

```
  has_many :resource_tags
  has_many :resources, :through => :resource_tags

  attr_accessible :name
  attr_protected :resource_count
```

resource.rb

```
after_save    :cache_resource_count_on_tags

def cache_resource_count_on_tags
  self.tags.each {|tag| tag.update_attribute(:resource_count, tag.resources.count)}
end
```

my migration:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|

      t.string  :name
      t.integer :resources_count, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks called after create and after destroy are after_create and after_destroy, as seen here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

So, in order to run something after some of those events, you could do this:

```
after_create :run_something
after_destroy :run_something

def run_something
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Do Ineed to worry about the resource_tag table?

Comment: Ok thanks! so this is my finalized code:
  `after_create  :add_favorite, :upvote_submitted_resource` ----
  `after_save    :cache_resource_count_on_tags`  ----
  `after_destroy :cache_resource_count_on_tags`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to do this:

```rb
after_commit :run_something, on: [:create, :destroy]
```

This will operate differently from:

```rb
after_create :run_something
after_destroy :run_something
```

As `after_commit` will not run the callback until after the database change (created or deletion) has been successfully committed.

Comment: @Tallboy I only provide the timeliest of answers lol. :-)